# Some items from Array works fine, but some of them not

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have created an Array in the main method. Then copied it to the array in another class. Then added all required information for the method and tried to use all 3 codes of a product (Aa/1234, Bb/1234, Cc/1234). The weird thing is that 1st and 3rd does not throw an exception, but 2nd does. Please indicate what is wrong. Thanks.

```
    try
    {
    Product product1 = new Product("Aa/1234", 20);
    Product product2 = new Product("Bb/1234", 30);
    Product product3 = new Product("Cc/1234", 40);        
    Product [] productRange = {product1, product2, product3};

    ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier management = 
                        new ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(1,12,productRange);

    System.arraycopy(productRange, 0, management.getProductRange(), 0,
                                                       productRange.length);        

    EducationalInstitutionDetails newInstitution = 
                           new EducationalInstitutionDetails("ESE-1234",
                                              "SE", myAddress, 1000, "UEA");

    management.addNewCustomer(newInstitution);
    management.addNewPurchaseOrder("21/01/12", "ESE-1234", "Bb/1234", 50);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The method:

```
 public void addNewPurchaseOrder(String dateStr, String customerID, 
         String productCode, int qty) throws IncorrectPurchaseOrderException
{

    Product foundProduct = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++)
    {   
        if(productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode))
        {   
            foundProduct = productRange[i];
            break;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }        
    if(foundProduct == null)
        throw new IncorrectPurchaseOrderException("Product code is not in"
                                                   + " the product range!");
```

Another thing if I would use boolean in the same method. Same question, what is wrong there?

```
    int i = 0;
    boolean match = productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode);
    while(i < productRange.length)
    {
        if(match)
            foundProduct = productRange[i];
            break;
        else
            i++;
    }
    if(!match)
        throw new IncorrectPurchaseOrderException("Product code is not in"
                                                   + " the product range!");
```

Thank you!

Exception:

```
public class IncorrectPurchaseOrderException extends Exception
```

{
    public IncorrectPurchaseOrderException(String wrongOrder)
    {
        super(wrongOrder);
    }
}

Comment: ... What's the exception?

Comment: The while loop, if you find the product, you never increment i, so won't it be an infinite loop?

Comment: user2348184, but "break" will not stop it from looping?

Comment: "Bb/1234" throws an exception, other 2 product codes not

Comment: you added break after my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is it, but it looks fishy to me:

```
for(int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++)
{   
    if(productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode))
    {   
        foundProduct = productRange[i];
        break;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
```

Basically every time you go through the for loop, if it's not a match your incrementing i twice. Once in the line

```
 for(int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++)
```

and then another time if it's not identified as having the product code. Try removing the else i++, it seems redundant and could be causing the issue.

Edit, yep I think its causing it to skip checking every other index, so half the time it's going to fail to find the correct product code if everything is unique in the array, depending on if it falls on an odd or even index.

Comment: I second that. You do not need to increment 'i' as it is already incremented by the for statement.

Comment: The thing with a second, I don't understand the principle of (!match). I know what it means, but for example: